# using ngx-charts when run ng build got error

Tags: angular, ngx-charts

installed ngx-chart 12.0.1
angular 11

when run ng build, got this error:
Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
using description file: C:\wwwroot\ngxchart\package.json (relative path: ./src/main/webapp/resources/typescript/aot/node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-charts/release/common/charts/chart.component)

expected  no error

Comment: looks like that version is only for angular 7 and 8 https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts/blob/12.0.1/package.json

Answer (score 0):

You need to look up what version of support for angular is supported when downloading packages. the one you download is only for angular 7-8 and hence would cause issues with rendering due to the render engine back then was using ViewEngine and i beleave in angular 11 you already on ivy.

for angular you need version 18.0.1 of ngx-charts

```
npm i @swimlane/ngx-charts@18.0.1
```

you can see the requirements in their package.json so for 12.0.1 the versions are angular 7 and 8
for 18.0.x its angular 11 which you use based on what you wrote.
https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts/blob/18.0.1/package.json